# How to use Cargo commands programmatically in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use Cargo commands (`cargo build` in this instance) programmatically without running the command with `std::process::Command` in Rust.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly why you want to do this, as there's probably A Better Way?

Comment: I can only have a process running due to the limitation my serverless-like container has.

Comment: Even if you drive Cargo programmatically, it doesn't call rustc in-process (and rustc doesn't call the linker in-process) so you still won't actually be able to compile anything.

Answer (score 13):

Add the [`cargo`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo) ([docs](https://docs.rs/cargo/)) crate to your dependencies, and you can use Cargo as a library! It doesn't have any stability guarantees or much documentation though, so you might want to read through [how the Cargo CLI tool uses the library](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/tree/master/src/bin/cargo) to figure out how to use it. To do a build, [`cargo::ops::compile`](https://docs.rs/cargo/0.56.0/cargo/ops/fn.compile.html) is the function to call.

But do keep in mind that the Cargo library will still run `rustc` in another process using `Command::new`, so this is really just moving where the process boundary is, not eliminating it entirely.